# Is it possible to link to image in supersized slideshow from an external page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

I am still trying to use the click event to function as a link that goes to a slide within supersized slideshow. Is it senseless? Please, if anyone has a hint of an idea i'd love to read about it.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

I am trying to use the .click function referenced for supersized slideshow.

```
api.goTo

$(element).click(function(){
api.goTo(5);
});
```

The function would work within the page, but how would i link from an external page? I have a page filled with thumbnails and am trying to link each thumbnail to the corresponding slide on the slideshow page. Not sure if this is even possible. Does anyone have experience with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Include the options parameter and use the suggested href

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981342/link-from-external-page-to-a-specific-slide-with-supersized/13984849#13984849

Answer (score 0):

Your link would best include the page number as a querystring variable, e.g.:

```
<a href="mydomain.com/myslideshow?page=5">Slideshow p.5</a>
```

Then you could obtain the querystring variable with some javascript (for an example of how to do this, see the fn defined as *getParameterByName* in: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript))

```
var pageNumber = getParameterByName(page);

$(element).click(function(){
    api.goTo(pageNumber);
});
```