# link from external page to a specific slide with Supersized

Tags: jquery, supersized

Is there anyway to link to a specific image in a supersized gallery from another page in my site. I have a homepage with multiple thumbnails corresponding to images in the supersized gallery. Is there a way to link each thumbnail so that when it goes to the supersized page it is on the correct slide?

This is how I have the script in the supersized page

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                // Size & Position                         
                min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'name', // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                {image : 'images/4change.jpg', title : 'slide-link-01', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/a1.jpg', title : 'slide-link-02', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/amplifon1.jpg', title : 'slide-link-03', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/amplifon2.jpg', title : 'slide-link-04', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/brain1.jpg', title : 'slide-link-05', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/brain2.jpg', title : 'slide-link-06', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/britishhandball.jpg', title : 'slide-link-07', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/britishhandball2.jpg', title : 'slide-link-08', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/cord.jpg', title : 'slide-link-09', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/crossborder1.jpg', title : 'slide-link-10', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/crossborder2.jpg', title : 'slide-link-11', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/guiness1.jpg', title : 'slide-link-12', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/guiness2.jpg', title : 'slide-link-13', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/harambee.jpg', title : 'slide-link-14', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/lifetracks.jpg', title : 'slide-link-15', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/missimo.jpg', title : 'slide-link-16', thumb : '', url : '' },
                {image : 'images/staffordshire.jpg', title : 'slide-link-17', thumb : '', url : '' },
                                             ],

                // Theme Options               
                progress_bar            :   1,
                // Timer for each slide                         
                mouse_scrub             :   0

            });
        });


 </script>
```

How to link image from another page ?

Comment: you want to add an image after initialise ?

Comment: If I was on the homepage and clicked on the thumbnail for slide-link-15 i would like it to go straight to slide-link-15 when the supersized page opens instead of starting at slide-link-01.

Comment: ah, you want to detect it from url ?

Answer (score 1):

To add image on the fly use `api.options.slides` array and `api._build()`;

for example:

```
api.options
      .slides.push({image: "http://placehold.it/350x150",title: "TEST"});
api._build();
```

please note that this plugin not looks good for me as it make a noise in global scope.

to goto to specific image you can use `api.goTo();` method. to link from another page you can use  hashlink:

on other page:

```
<a href="/galery.html#im=15">
```

after init supersized:

```
api.goTo(document.location
                   .hash
                    .replace(/^#/,'')
                     .replace(/im=([0-9]+).*$/,'$1'))
```

or if you need to make it on start just use  `start_slide` option :

```
$.supersized({
            // ..... options 
            start_slide : document.location
                                    .hash
                                     .replace(/^#/,'')
                                      .replace(/im=([0-9]+).*$/,'$1')),  
            // ..... options 
});
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for! Thankyou I will try it out today!